# postresql group by query taking too long

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I am running the below query and it's takig 5 minutes,

```
SELECT "DID" 
FROM location_signals 
GROUP BY "DID";
```

I have an index on DID, which is variable char 100,  the table has about 150 million records
how to improve and optimize this further ?
is there any additional indexes that can be added or recommendations? thanks

edit: below results of explain analyse query:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=23803276.36..24466411.92 rows=179625 width=44) (actual time=285577.900..321360.237 rows=4833061 loops=1)
  Group Key: DID
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=23803276.36..24462819.42 rows=359250 width=44) (actual time=285577.874..320018.354 rows=10825153 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=23802276.33..24420353.03 rows=179625 width=44) (actual time=281580.548..310818.137 rows=3608384 loops=3)
              Group Key: DID
              ->  Sort  (cost=23802276.33..24007703.15 rows=82170727 width=36) (actual time=281580.535..303887.638 rows=65736579 loops=3)
                    Sort Key: DID
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2987656kB
                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3099408kB
                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2987648kB
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on location_signals  (cost=0.00..6259493.27 rows=82170727 width=36) (actual time=0.043..13460.990 rows=65736579 loops=3)
Planning Time: 1.332 ms
Execution Time: 322686.767 ms
```

Comment: this is the result of explain analyse on the above query: https://snag.gy/PcsT8S.jpg

Comment: done, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: One reason why it's slow, is that the grouping is done on disk, rather than in memory. Does your server have enough memory, so that you can increase `work_mem` to a substantially higher value? Increasing `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` (and `max_parallel_workers`)  might also improve performance because it will speed up doing the Seq Scan (assuming that your harddisks can sustain the additional I/O load)

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using (`select version();` will tell you)